# Adding a row with columns that have sequenced primary and foreign key JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

My program has an *add item* and *finish transaction* option. The `FinishTransaction` class asks the user to input the customer's information, method of payment, and the payment.

The total payment is displayed at the window. When the user click the *checkout* button, the data should be transferred from the `CUSTOMER` table (insert the customer's information), `ORDERS` table (insert the item's information bought), and the `TRANSACTION` table (insert the transaction information).

The transaction table has a column of `TRANS_CUSTNUM` that is a foreign key referenced to the `CUST_NUM` in the `CUSTOMER` table.

My program works fine except at the `TRANSACTION` table. It does not add a row in my SQL developer. What do you think is wrong in my code?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class FinishTransaction extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel totalLabel;
    JLabel nameLabel;
    JLabel addressLabel;
    JLabel contactLabel;
    JLabel custPaymentLabel;
    JLabel methodLabel;
    JLabel creditCardLabel;
    JTextField totalTextField;
    JTextField nameTextField;
    JTextField addressTextField;
    JTextField contactTextField;
    JTextField custPaymentTextField;
    JTextField creditCardTextField;
    final JButton mainMenuButton = new JButton("Main Menu");
    final ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    final JRadioButton cashRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Cash");
    final JRadioButton creditRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Credit Card");
    final JButton checkoutButton = new JButton("Checkout");

    static FinishTransaction fin = new FinishTransaction();
    static AddItem add = new AddItem();
    static int total = 0;
    static int payment = 0;
    static int change = 0;
    static String payment_desc;
    static int creditCard;

    public FinishTransaction(){
        //ui
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(checkoutButton.getName().equals(((Component)e.getSource()).getName())){
            try{
                payment = Integer.parseInt(custPaymentTextField.getText());
                if(payment>=total){
                    change = payment - total;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Thank you for shopping! Your change is "+change, "Exiting", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your payment is not enough. Please try again!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException a){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid input", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt3 = null;
            String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@VAIO:49160:xe";
            String USER = "mariel";
            String PASS = "1234";

            try {
                  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                try {
                    String name = nameTextField.getText();
                    String address = addressTextField.getText();
                    int contact = Integer.parseInt(contactTextField.getText());
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " + 
                            "VALUES(CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?)";
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pstmt.setString(1, name);
                    pstmt.setString(2, address);
                    pstmt.setInt(3, contact);

                    pstmt.executeUpdate();

                    for(int index=0;index<add.itemNum.length;index++){
                        String sql2 = "INSERT INTO ORDERS "+
                                "VALUES(OrderNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?)";    
                        pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                        pstmt2.setInt(1,add.itemNum[index]);
                        pstmt2.setInt(2, add.quantity[index]);

                        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
                    }

                    creditCard = Integer.parseInt(creditCardTextField.getText());
                    String sql3 = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION " + 
                            "VALUES(TransNumSeq.NEXTVAL, CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
                    pstmt3.setInt(1, payment);
                    pstmt3.setString(2, payment_desc);
                    pstmt3.setInt(3, creditCard);
                    pstmt3.setInt(4, change);

                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException a){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid input", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException a){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid input", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            finally{
                try{
                   if(pstmt!=null)
                      pstmt.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se2){
                }
                try{
                   if(pstmt2!=null)
                      pstmt2.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se2){
                }
                try{
                   if(pstmt3!=null)
                      pstmt3.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se2){
                }
                try{
                   if(conn!=null)
                   conn.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se){
                }
            }
        }
        else if(mainMenuButton.getName().equals(((Component)e.getSource()).getName())){
            EmployeeMode emp = new EmployeeMode();
            emp.setVisible(true);
            emp.setResizable(false);
            emp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            emp.setSize(400,300);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
        if(creditRadioButton.isSelected()){
            creditCardLabel.setVisible(true);
            creditCardTextField.setVisible(true);
            payment_desc = "Credit Card";
        }
        else if(cashRadioButton.isSelected()){
            creditCardLabel.setVisible(false);
            creditCardTextField.setVisible(false);
            payment_desc = "Cash";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        fin.setVisible(true);
        fin.setResizable(false);
        fin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fin.setSize(500,400);
    }
}
```

(EDITED)
Working generated code:

```
                        String name = nameTextField.getText();
                        String address = addressTextField.getText();
                        int contact = Integer.parseInt(contactTextField.getText());
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

                        for(int index=0;index<add.itemNum.length;index++){
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO ORDERS "+
                                    "VALUES(OrderNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?)";    
                            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                            pstmt.setInt(1,add.itemNum[index]);
                            pstmt.setInt(2, add.quantity[index]);

                            pstmt.executeUpdate();
                        }

                        String sql2 = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " + 
                                "VALUES(CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?)";
                        String generatedColumns[] = {"CUST_NUM"};
                        pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2, generatedColumns);
                        pstmt2.setString(1, name);
                        pstmt2.setString(2, address);
                        pstmt2.setInt(3, contact);
                        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
                        ResultSet rs = pstmt2.getGeneratedKeys();
                        custNum = rs.getInt("CUST_NUM");

                        creditCard = Integer.parseInt(creditCardTextField.getText());
                        String sql3 = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION " + 
                            "VALUES(TransNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
                        pstmt3.setInt(1, custNum);
                        pstmt3.setInt(2, payment);
                        pstmt3.setString(3, payment_desc);
                        pstmt3.setInt(4, creditCard);
                        pstmt3.setInt(5, change);

                        pstmt3.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: have you commited connection ..I don't see in snippet

Comment: In code after completing your transaction to persist data "conn.commit();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this sql insert statement is incorrect.

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION " + 
                        "VALUES(TransNumSeq.NEXTVAL,  CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?)";
```

You're inserting a record into TRANSACTION and trying to advance the sequence on CUSTOMER (CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL) . You should try to use

```
//when inserting into CUSTOMER 
pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pstmt.execute();//make the insert
//and then simply grab the key
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) 
id = rs.getObject(1);
```

Note that not every JDBC driver supports returning generated keys so you may have to use one additional select to fetch the last generated key.

And finally, you will have to change this part to reflect the changes made above

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO TRANSACTION " + 
                        "VALUES(TransNumSeq.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
pstmt3.setInt(1, id);
pstmt3.setInt(2, payment);
pstmt3.setString(3, payment_desc);
pstmt3.setInt(4, creditCard);
pstmt3.setInt(5, change);
```

Comment: does the id part should be `static int id;` or `FinishTransaction id = new FinishTransaction();`?

Comment: If your sequence is integer, then just use int id = rs.getInt(1)

Comment: Do i have to make another `stmt.executeUpdate` that moves the generated key into the variable for it to work? ~I'll try to code this tomorrow.~

Comment: No. The key is returned in ResultSet rs = PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();. Note that you can check whether this feature is available by calling the java.sql.DataBaseMetadata.supportsGetGeneratedKeys() method.

Comment: The generated key now works but only the first prepared statement only inserts in the table. It's a different problem so i'm gonna create a new one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't see that you are maintaining any transaction in your code.
2) In case, if there is any error in the last insert, you'll not be able to see the data in 3rd table. Check your logs for any exception while making insert into third table.
3) Problem that looks quite obvious to me is:

```
"INSERT INTO TRANSACTION " + 
                            "VALUES(TransNumSeq.NEXTVAL, **CustNumSeq.NEXTVAL**, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

...You are calling the sequence second time, it will have different cust_no than what you have inserted in the first statement.
4) In case, you have defined the cust_num as foreign key in transaction table, the code should break. Because this cust_num doesn't exist in customer table yet.

Comment: How do i make it so it'll have an equal number of cust_no?

Comment: Make a select on sequence, then store the number in  a variable. Use that  number consequently.

Comment: Or use the JDBC `getGeneratedKeys` facility.