# Retrieve Autoincrement value after INSERT query in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a requirement to update two tables simultaneously. For example, I have two tables: `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` and `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`. While adding a row in `CUSTOMER_DETAILS`, a few details, like `address`, are first written in `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` and its reference is added in `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` table.

Now if `ADD_ID` is a primary key in `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` table and if it is an auto increment field than how to add this key as a foreign key in `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` table using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

How do I also write these 2 MySQL queries in a JSP file in `register.html`?

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (ADD_ID, ADD_TEXT) VALUES(NULL, 'some address value');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DETAILS (NAME, ADD_ID, GENDER, PHONE_NO) VALUES ('James Bond', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'MALE', 007);
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529827/adding-a-row-with-columns-that-have-sequenced-primary-and-foreign-key-jdbc/34530360#34530360

Comment: Thanks. I solved it.

Comment: int i= st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `parent`() VALUES ()", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

  ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

 int autoIncValue = 0;


 while (rs.next()) {
  /* { */
  autoIncValue = rs.getInt(1);