# JDBC MSSQL Insert fails with error "near where"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a strange problem. I'm executing insert using prepared statement like this:

```
try (Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) { //TODO: caching of PS
    int i = 1;
    ParameterMetaData pmd = ps.getParameterMetaData();
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new TGFIOException("Error executing SQL command " + sql, e);
}
```

Insert statement is like this:

```
 insert into dbo.CurrencyRates(RateDate, CurrencyID, Rate) values ( ?, ?, ? )
```

Unfortunately it fails with following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerParameterMetaData.<init>(SQLServerParameterMetaData.java:426)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1532)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.getParameterMetaData(PreparedStatementHandle.java:246)
```

There is no WHERE in the statement, so I am puzzled why it fails on metadata extraction...

**EDIT:**

SQL Server = 10.50.2500.0 Express Edition, 
Driver = sqljdbc4.jar from 4.0 package

Also, I am using getParameterMetaData because I need to set some params to null and the preferred method is to use setNull() where you need SQLType.

**EDIT2:**
I've tested with Driver sqljdbc41 from newest 6.0 package - results are the same

**EDIT3:**
I've removed call to getParameterMetaData() and it worked, unfortunately it is a generic part that should max portable, yet it does not work with this single table (inserts to other tables on the same database works fine !!!)

**EDIT4:** 
I've tried with different insert statements for this table and all of them works fine if I skip `ps.getParameterMetaData()` and fail when I call it. If I try with 2 or more params I get usual `near WHERE` error. If I try one column insert I get an error stating that the column name is incorrect, even if it is correct and without the meta data call it works perfectly fine. I will try to trace what driver tries to do underneath...

Comment: Are you sure whether its failing while executing insert statement? It seems some select statement execution is failing .

Comment: Maybe it's because of `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` and the driver adds some additional conditions to the statement to make that happen. You could try tracing the statements sent to the server. It might also be that `getParameterMetaData()` requires a second roundtrip to the database and during that a statement is sent that isn't valid. Which version of the driver and which SQL Server version are you using? Maybe they don't match.

Comment: where you are setting prepared statement insert values ? like setint set string etc.

Comment: please add `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true` in connection string then try to run.

Comment: Why do you need to call getParameterMetadata(). If you only need to return the generated (inserted) key, then you can simply call ps.getGeneratedKeys() and extract the key from the ResultSet.

Comment: You can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529827/adding-a-row-with-columns-that-have-sequenced-primary-and-foreign-key-jdbc/34530360#34530360

Comment: So, it turns the insert statement is correct, because just removing `ps.getParameterMetaData()` it make it work, unfortunately, this way I am not able to set null parameter the recommended way as according to Javadoc I should use `ps.setNull(<num>, <sqlType>)` yet I cannot get the type dynamically... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tracing on what actually the driver does (many thanks *a_horse_with_no_name*), I've come to some funny conclusion.

The solution for my question is to:

Replace following insert statement

- `INSERT INTO CurrencyRates(RateDate, CurrencyID, Rate) VALUES (  ?, ?, ? )`

With this statement

- `INSERT INTO CurrencyRates (RateDate, CurrencyID, Rate) VALUES (  ?, ?, ? )`

Logic behind that is that SQL driver does some metadata extraction in the background, and it creates a query with following fragment: `... FROM CurrencyRates(RateDate WHERE ...` if you do not put space after table name, yet for the ordinary call this is perfectly possible!

**EDIT:**
This is obviously an inconsistency as (putting aside what actually is a valid insert) it should consistently accept or reject this query no matter if I call for meta data or not.

Comment: Unbelievable, but this indeed solved my problem, which persists even as late as version 8.2.1.jre8.  Many thanks!